# Find all contiguous subsequences of an array of sum k

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming, subsequence, contiguous

Example:

The array is as follows: `-4 -10 -15 - 20 100 -67 47 20` and
`k = 51`

Expected output:

`-4 -10 -15 - 20 100`

`-4 -10 -15 - 20 100 -67 47 20`

Tried the brute force solution with O(n^2). Can anyone please suggest a better solution to this?

Comment: There are `(n-1)^2` contiguous sub-sequences of an array. I'm afraid analysing them all can only be done in `O(n^2)` time, can't it?

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in `O(nlogn)`.

We solve a simple problem first:

```
For an array, find two elements in the array which sum is k.
```

So, we could do it:

`algo_1`

```
pre = []
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if pre.elementValueIs(k - array[i])
     output()
  pre.add(array[i])
}
```

By BST(Java.util.Map, C++ map, Python dict) or binary search, we could do `pre.elementValueIs` in `O(logn)`

So in the summary, we could get a `O(nlogn)` algorithm.

And for your question, we make another new array s[], which

```
s[i] = a[i] + a[i - 1] + ... + a[0]
```

So if `a[p] + a[p + 1] ... + a[q] = k(p<=q)`, `s[q] - s[p - 1]` = k.

In this way, we could solve your problem by `algo_1`.

I write a Java code for your and you can debug it for more details:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sayakiss on 8/13/15.
 */
public class SubSum {

    static class SumArray {
        private int[] sumArray;

        public SumArray(int[] inputArray) {
            sumArray = new int[inputArray.length + 1];
            sumArray[0] = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                sumArray[i + 1] = inputArray[i] + sumArray[i];
            }
        }

        //get input sum(array[i]) (begin<=i<=end)
        public int getSum(int begin, int end) {
            return sumArray[end + 1] - sumArray[begin];
        }
    }

    static void printResult(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        for(int i = begin; i<= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
            if (i != end) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void subSum(int[] inputArray, int k) {
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();//sum(a[0..i]) = key
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(0);
        map.put(0, list);

        SumArray sumArray = new SumArray(inputArray);
        for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            int sum = sumArray.getSum(0, i);
            List<Integer> beginIndexList = map.get(k - sum);
            if (beginIndexList != null) {
                for(int beginIndex : beginIndexList)
                    printResult(inputArray, beginIndex, i);
            }
            List<Integer> integerList = map.get(sum);
            if (integerList == null) {
                integerList = new ArrayList<>();
                map.put(sum, integerList);
            }
            integerList.add(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        subSum(new int[]{-4, -10, -15, -20, 100, -67, 47, 20}, 51);
    }
}
```

If you run my main function, you will get output(the same as your test case):

```
-4, -10, -15, -20, 100
-4, -10, -15, -20, 100, -67, 47, 20
```